# How to set bold font instead font weight in Bootstrap 4 SCSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I'm trying to build Bootstrap from SCSS, but I'm not experienced in front-end technologies at all. Is there any way to set a bold-by-default font instead font-weight everywhere it's used? The font-weight version is rendered distorted. I'm using a custom CSS now overriding the font-family everywhere where it's needed (h1...h6, b, strong, etc.) but it's not too convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use font-weight-bold class to get bold font.

Comment: Add the class .font-weight-bold to the ‘body’ tag.

Answer (score 0):

Load a bold font by default:

```css
*{
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:900" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p>etc.</p>
<span>everything is bold now</span>
```

Comment: Maybe my problem description was wrong: I only want to swap to the bold font where font-weight is set, so it's rendered smoother, not everything. :)

Comment: I don't think that kind of filter is available through css, but you could set a class for the elements you want to use a different font for, defining a smoother font for these ones.